# iText PDF - How to add multiline footer?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, footer

I am able to add a single line footer to the generated PDF using iText PDF but I need to add a multiline footer.

I have tried that concatenating two strings with the new line character of Java (`\n`) but no chance (*see Code #1*). Also, have tried to set the multiline footer through the `float x, float y` parameters of `onEndPage` method of the class `PdfPageEventHelper`. Did not work too (*see Code #2*).

Here is what I have tried so far:

**Code #1**

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("line1" + "\n" + "line2", fontNormal10);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, 40, 30, 0);
```

**Code #2**

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("line1", fontNormal10);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, 40, 30, 0);
Phrase phrase2 = new Phrase("line2", fontNormal10);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase2, 40, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `ColumnText.showTextAligned()`. That is a method that you can use to *add a single line of text.* You shouldn't expect it to work to add multiple lines of text.

If you want to add more than one line, you have to define a `Rectangle`, and you have to use `ColumnText` to add the content inside this rectangle. This is (of course) explained in the official documentation, more specifically in the section [Absolute positioning of text (iText 5)](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/absolute-positioning-text) where you will find the question [How to add text inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-inside-rectangle)

The code in the answer to that question is C# code, but it's easy to convert it to Java:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
ct.addElement(new Paragraph("This is the text added in the rectangle"));
ct.go();
```

Define the values of `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` in such a way that all the text fits into the rectangle (text that doesn't fit will be omitted), and in such a way that it is positioned at the bottom of the page.